# Download Buttons for Github Pages

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

When selecting the theme for the github page of an existing repository, you can see this set of buttons (in the Minimal theme, for example):
[image]

But when I visit my github pages site, the buttons are not there; all I can see is my `readme.md` for the repository, and the *View the Project on GitHub* link. Is there a way to get these buttons on my page?

Comment: try log out and visit again

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just add `show_downloads: true` to your _config.yml

Comment: Thank you! How did you know what the flag was? Is there a list of these somewhere?

Comment: I check theme config file https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal/blob/master/_config.yml

Comment: I had the opposite problem: I wanted to hide the links. Changing the _config.yml worked!

Comment: I don't have a `_config.yml`. Is this a file we should be creating ourselves? Just drop it in the root of the repository beside the ReadMe.md?

Comment: I never noticed that when enabling GitHub Pages it automatically adds the `_config.yml` file to the repo, so I just had to pull the latest changes from the repository and then I saw the file.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, but I had the same problem and the chosen answer didn't help me out. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44659128/602585) on another SO question. Basically it says your options are:

- Add links to the downloads at the top of your README.md. The zip link is (https://github.com/parsiad/mlinterp/archive/v0.1.zip) and the tar ball link is (https://github.com/parsiad/mlinterp/archive/v0.1.tar.gz). You can create links in Markdown easily; instructions for links can be found [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#links). Once the links are added to your README.md, they will appear on your auto-generated site.
- Change your theme to something like [Modernist](https://github.com/pages-themes/modernist) that comes with the download links by default.
- Instead of automatically generating your GitHub Pages site, pull it into your repository and modify it yourself. You would then be able to add a link to the top of your theme next to the one that is already there.

---

**Update**

I never noticed that enabling GitHub Pages on the GitHub repository automatically added the `_config.yml` file to the repository, so once I pulled the latest changes from the remote repository I saw the file and was able to simply add `show_downloads: true` to it as Abdul Hadi's answer suggests. I'm leaving the above suggestions in this answer though, as they are still applicable if you are trying to have the download links show in a theme that does not natively support them.