# Github-pages: download release

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a GitHub repository.

Though I have made a release of the project, the corresponding download link does not appear on the page (I used the gh-pages wizard to create this page).

Any suggestions to get the usual "download latest tarball/zip" download links?

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43979944/9216024)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using an auto generated GitHub Pages site. To get the download links on your site, you have three options.

- Add links to the downloads at the top of your README.md. The zip link is

  ```
  https://github.com/username/project/archive/v0.1.zip
  ```

  and the tar ball link is

  ```
  https://github.com/username/project/archive/v0.1.tar.gz
  ```

  You can create links in Markdown easily; instructions for links can be found [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#links). Once the links are added to your README.md, they will appear on your auto-generated site.
- Change your theme to something like [Modernist](https://github.com/pages-themes/modernist) that comes with the download links by default.
- Instead of automatically generating your GitHub Pages site, pull it into your repository and modify it yourself. You would then be able to add a link to the top of your theme next to the one that is already there.